# Why is it still executing even if the file only has a 0 in it?

Tags: lua

This should check if the file has a zero in it and if its not a zero it should execute the code.
But it still executes the code even if it only has a zero in it.

```
f = io.open("timesave.txt", "r")
if (f ~= 0) then
    io.input(f)
    resultstart = f:read("*line")
    resultstop = f:read("*line")
    f:close()
end
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do - do you want to check if file contains only one character - 0 or if it has 0 in any line?

Comment: if the file only contains the number 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io.open("timesave.txt", "r")` returns a file handle if successful or nil.

From: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.open

> **io.open (filename [, mode])**
>
> This function opens a file, in the mode specified in the string mode.
> In case of success, it returns a new file handle.
> ...

You cannot use io.open to check wether a file contains a zero.

In order to do that you need to open the file, read and check its content.

```
-- open the file in read mode
local f = io.open("timesave.txt", "rb")
-- check wether the file has been opened
if not f then print("failed to open file") return end
-- read and check wether there is only a 0 in the file.
if f:read("a") == "\0" then print("file only contains \\0") end
f:close()
```